# i need to make more than one ime entry into the supplier model how can i do that? it only allow one ime

Tags: django

i have an ime model like that

```
class Imee(models.Model):
    ime_number = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ime_number

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ghaith:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

and i have a supplier model and i need to enter more then one ime to the supplier and more than a receipt

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)
    imee = models.ForeignKey(Imee,related_name='suppliers',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receipt_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,null=False)
    receipt_date = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplier_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ghaith:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Please show us how you're trying to add an ime entry and what is the error that Django gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have more that one imee per supplier the foreign key should be in the Imee model

```py
class Imee(models.Model):
    ime_number = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, related_name='imees',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)
    receipt_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,null=False)
    receipt_date = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=False)
```

You'll then be able to add new imee to a supplier by calling

```py
my_supplier.imees.add(my_imee)
```